# USB devices not showing

Tags: usb-device, system-programming

I'm trying to write a C program that goes through all USB devices and extracts some information from them. When I run `ls /sys/bus/usb/devices` from the terminal, I get this output:

```
1-0:1.0    1-1.1      1-1.2      1-1.2:1.1  usb1
1-1        1-1.1:1.0  1-1.2:1.0  1-1:1.0
```

However, running `ls` within a `system()` call in C only shows the following devices:

```
1-0:1.0    1-1        1-1.1      1-1.1:1.0  1-1:1.0    usb1
```

I can't think of a reason why the rest of the devices aren't showing, maybe something to do with permissions? Is there anyway to get all of them to display?